# match pattern nth digit of a number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex `/^(\+88)?01[3-9]\d{8}$/`

```
let phoneNum = "+880136486336"

let validRegex = /^(\+88)?01[3-9]\d{8}$/;

console.log(validRegex.test(phoneNum));
```

to match a pattern that matches some strings like

```
+8801712345678
01712345678
01312349876
```

It works fine but I also want to match `01[n]` where `n` will be `3-9`. pattern to find out the mobile network operator.

I want to do something like this

> if the number is **01712345678** then print "Network Operator A",
>
> if the number is **+8801712345678** then print "Network Operator A"
>
> if the number is **01312349678** then print "Network Operator B"
>
> and different operators for different values of `n`.
>
> **here `017, 013, 014, 016, 015, 019, 018` are mobile operator codes** which I want to use to find out operator based on the mobile number.

I don't find any way to do it.
How can I do it with regex?

Comment: But isn't that already in your pattern? See the `01[3-9]` part. Or do you want to say `\d{8}` should not match `0`, `1`, `2`?

Comment: I want to do like if 017 is in the number then print "A text" or if 013 is in the then print "C text", how can I do that?

Comment: Capture the digit, `let validRegex = /^(?:\+88)?01([3-9])\d{8}$/;`, then use `const found = phoneNum.match(validRegex)` and then `if (found) { if (validRegex[1] == '7') { console.log('A text');} else {console.log('C text');}}` or something like that. Please update the question, it is not clear what to do in other scenarios

Comment: I EDITED the question it hopes it's more understandable now.

Comment: Ok, but `+8801712345678` cannot be `Op. B` if `01712345678` is `Op. A`, there is `7` in both.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *capture* the three digits at the start with a capturing group, then use `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` to get the actual match and then, if there is a match, get the group value and obtain the operator name from a dictionary:

```js
const phones = ['+8801712345678','01712345678','01312349876'];
const operators = {'017' : 'Operator A', '013' : 'Operator C', '014' : 'Operator B', '016' : 'Operator D', '015' : 'Operator E', '019' : 'Operator F', '018' : 'Operator G'};
const validRegex = /^(?:\+88)?(01[3-9])\d{8}$/; 
for (const phone of phones) {
  const match = validRegex.exec(phone);
  if (match) {
    console.log(phone, "=> Valid, belongs to", operators[match[1]])
  } else {
    console.log(phone,"=> NO MATCH");
  }
}
```

Here,

- `^(?:\+88)?(01[3-9])\d{8}$`: the first optional group  is now non-capturing and there is a capturing group with ID = 1 now, `(01[3-9])`
- `validRegex.exec(phone)` gets the match object
- `operators[match[1]]` returns the Operator name by the key.